# Logging to remote server without specifying username

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ssh-keys

Today I configured ssh keys access to my server. Then I tested them and by mistake I forgot to specify the user, so instead of doing it like that:

```
ssh username@myserver.com
```

I did it like that

```
ssh myserver.com
```

but I successfully logged in as `username`. How is that possible? How does `ssh` server know under which user to log me in? If it's a key, than it's possible that I'll have the same key added to multiple users, what's going to happen in this case?

Comment: Way of Saddam Abu Ghaida it's correct. For me it's easy. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and copy into users (remote server) authorized_keys /path/user/.ssh/authorized_keys. Now, i can connect without put user on command on this user on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you didn't include the username in the ssh command it will take the username that you logged in with from the environment, so there is two possibilities for what happened, 1. the username which is related to the ssh key is the username that you logged in with, or the other username that you logged in with has the his public key in the authorized_keys file in the server side